# not getting albumart on lockscreen inspite of putting bitmap in metadata

Tags: android

i am unable to get albumart on lockscreen , i have tried using both METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART and METADATA_KEY_ART but nothing worked .here is my code

```
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        mmr.setDataSource(music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getPath());
        data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (music.getNowPlayingList()!=null && music.getNowPlayingList().size()>music.getIndexOfCurrentSong()) {

        GildeUtils.getBitmapFromGlide(this,data , new GlideInterface() {
            @Override
            public void getBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
                //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nowplaying);
                        mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART,bitmap)
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON,bitmap)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getArtist())
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getAlbum())
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getTitle())
                        .build());
            }
        });
    }
```

i have also made mediastyle notification and also set the albumart as large icon as mentioned in other questions, also added mediasession.setActive(true) and audio focus nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally it worked for me :) Added Playbackstate code and everything seems to be working fine now.

```
GildeUtils.getBitmapFromGlide(this,data , new GlideInterface() {
            @Override
            public void getBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if(bitmap==null) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nowplaying);
                }
                        mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART,bitmap)
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON,bitmap)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getArtist())
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getAlbum())
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, music.getNowPlayingList().get(currentIndex).getTitle())
                        .build());
                PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
                isLockscreenUpdated = true;
                stateBuilder.setActiveQueueItemId(music.getNowPlayingList().get(music.getIndexOfCurrentSong()).getId());

                long actions = PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS;

                stateBuilder.setActions(actions);
                stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f);
                mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
            }


        });
```